# Mean matching size

Tags: probability, graph-theory, computer-science

Suppose there is a simple bipartite graph $G(X,E,Y)$, where $|X|=n_1$, $|Y|=n_2$, $|E|=m$. The edges $E$ are chosen uniformly at random.

The question is what is a mean value of the size of the maximum matching in such graph. $E(|M_{max}|) = ?$

To be honestly, I didn't think about this problem yet, it came just now to my mind, but seems pretty intresting and not really hard.

Comment: Hmmm, the tooltip for the downvote button does say "This question does not show any research effort..."

Comment: I don't looking for the solution as it was my homework or something. This problem just looks interesting for me, and, probably, not only for me. I don't wait you to go and solve it for me :)

Comment: If you still want "efforts": my idea is to count $P(|M|=k)$, which is equivalent to probaility that there is a matching of size k and there isn't any augmenting path. We can also count $P(|M| \ge k)$ for every  $k$ and get $P(|M| = k)$ from it. The second way seems much easier.